# Arcpy Join field options

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins

I am looping through Municipalities and clipping a layer called AllZones containing Multiple Facility (FACID) with multiple chemicals per Facility (CID). 1 to many relationship

```
           FacilityID,        CID,  other rows......
ex rows:        001              2           
                001              2           
                001              2          
                001              5           
                001              5          
                001              7         
                001              7           
                002              11         
                002              12          
                002              14
```

that result layer I then dissolve it down just by the FACID (call it labeldissolve) so I can generate 1 label for each facility on the map based on the new objected id.

```
   OBJECTID,  FacilityID
       1          001
       2          002
```

My next step is to create a report of the AllZones layer info for that given municipality. I want those created OBJECTID labels in the labeldissolve layer to correspond to the report. I tried joining the two tables in ArcMap based on the FACID and it works fine.

[image]

When I tried it in arcpy I did not have the option to choose keep only matching records

here is my code

```
arcpy.JoinField_management("AllZones", "FACID", "LabelDissolve", "FACID","")
```

should I be using a spatial join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not spatial join, it's still an attribute join. I have not used either of these arcpy functions myself, but it looks like 
`AddJoin_management()` has some options to specify the join type KEEP_COMMON:

[Add Join - ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-join.htm)

Comment: perfect-very surprised the regular arcpy.JoinField_management tool does not have the KEEP_COMMON join type option

Comment: @ziggy Join Field adds the join table data to your input table (it modifies the table).  It won't remove any data from your input table, which is why `KEEP_COMMON` isn't an option.